# Change color of LCD digits in Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt-designer, lcd

I'm writing a simple Python GUI with QtD.
I cannot find out (if possible) how I can change the color of the LCD digits. They are same color as the background and very difficult to see.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a stylesheet seems to work fine for me. In QDesigner, right-click the lcd widget (or better yet, the top widget), click 'Change stylesheet' and paste in the following text:

```
QLCDNumber{
    color: rgb(255, 89, 242);    
    background-color: rgb(0, 85, 0);
}
```

When you press OK, you should have an QLCDNumber with pink digits on a green background

I just picked some colors at random, don't judge me on the horrible combination! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP, where the numbers were difficult to read. Using Junuxx' solution, I could only change the background color, but not the color of the text.

After some experimenting, I found that I also had to change the `segmentStyle` setting of the `QLCDNumber` from "Outline" to "Flat". With that change, Junuxx' CSS worked as expected, but also the default colors had a much better contrast, so I didn't need to adjust them anymore.

(I'm working with `PySide2`/`Qt 5.15.2`)